# Working remotely with Mac

Tags: remote-desktop

I've Macbook Pro which I'm using now. I want to buy a new computer and I am between choosing Mac Pro (if new one comes out) and buying a standard PC which will be more powerful than Mac Pro for the same price (4000-5000 euro). Since I want to keep having Mac System for some tasks I thought of buying Mac Mini and connecting to it remotely. I know it's done via VNC but was wondering how's the "work" with it? I mean with Windows systems RDP is quite reliable on newest systems and you can really do a lot without feeling it's actually a remote desktop. With my old "VNC" days it always was somewhat pain to do so. Is it still so? I'm heavy Windows user so I use Parallels a lot but I like some features of Mac (sms sending, photos and few other features) so I would like to have both worlds.. not necessary buying Mac Pro which will be overpaid (hardware wise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes down to this statement:

> I'm heavy Windows user so I use Parallels a lot but I like some
>   features of Mac (sms sending, photos and few other features) so I
>   would like to have both worlds.. not necessary buying Mac Pro which
>   will be overpaid (hardware wise)

Get the PC that you like, get a cheap (even pre-owned) Mac like a Mac Mini or a MacBook Air and connect them via a KVM switch that will handle switching your monitor, keyboard, and mouse.

Or...

You could just get a 4K Video Switch and get a Bluetooth mouse and keyboard that supports multiple devices ([Logitech][3] has a number of multi-device Bluetooth products).  I have a Logitech mouse and keyboard that supports 3 devices each and I easily switch between my iMac, my Surface Pro, and a BSD machine with a BT dongle with no problems.  Obviously, my iMac and Surface have their own screens and I only need the mouse, keyboard, and video on the BSD box when I have to work directly on the console (which is rare)

I do a lot of different work on different platforms and I can say that VNC is horrible over a LAN connection.  If you plan on doing things like Photos or anything graphic related, you are going to want a direct (not remote) video

Comment: I do know KVM but wanted to avoid it. But if VNC is horrible even on the lan than I guess I have no option but a) Buy a Mac and accept consequences for hardware b) Buy a PC and Mac Mini and accept KVM.

Comment: I only use VNC in dire emergencies because it's so bad.  Give it a shot...if you have a friend with a Mac, try using VNC to see how it works for you.

Comment: Ye, it's always been bad on any platform but thought maybe there were some upgrades to technology. Windows RDP with its newest options really works nice. In new setup I plan 4 monitors and optionally a 5th one if there's a need so I'm a bit afraid of complications when it comes down to switching things with KVM.

Comment: That's a lot of monitors.  Have you thought of putting OS X in a VM?  I am not "officially" recommending due to Apple licensing, but it might be something you want to research.

Comment: Yes I did some research that way but also have no experience with it. Also I'm a bit afraid it will be hard to get updates and things won't work like on "mac". Always being problematic, especially with newest systems. Do you have any insight regarding that? As in will it work a bit like native or will it kill me like VNC does :-)

Comment: I have seen it used with Photos and other native Apple apps with no tech problems, however, I haven't seen it under heavy load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39335/discussion-between-madboy-and-allan).